# jquery .data put value

Tags: jquery

I have a DIV tag as such

```
    <div id='idval'></div>
```

in jquery I have the following

```
    var data1 = '<b>' + Text for file + '</b>'
```

how do I use the .data to assign the content of data1 so it appears in the div tab

final result would be something like:

```
    <div id='idval'>
    <b>Text for file </b>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use `data`, you use `.html()`.

```
$("#idval").html(data1);
```

May be worth reading the documentation on `data` to see what it is used for.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Answer (score 0):

By doing something like this:

```
$('#idval').html(data1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#idval').html(data1);
```

Six more characters needed

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple answer:

```
$('#idval').html(data1);
```

(Updated as suggested in the comments)

Comment: This is wrong, it will escape the `<b>` tag and display it instead of interpreting it and making the text bold.